# How to Yii app protected connection string?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, connection-string, password-protection

I'm hosting a Yii app on shared-host with some my friend, and keep database in private MySQL server. As you knew, database info can be found so very easy in `protected\config\main.php` by another host owner (my friend and more):

```
'db'=>array(
     'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=211.113.2.45;dbname=FamilyBook',
     'emulatePrepare' => true,
     'username' => root,
     'password' => 'xcute445',
     'charset' => 'utf8',
),
```

**Is there any solution to conceal connection information as IP mySQL server, username, password?**

May MySQL server provide [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) mechanism to protect database info?

Example, any people can see as below but cannot understand or use:

```
'db'=>array(
     'connectionString' => '57bf064b2166366a5ea61109006b8d5c',
     'emulatePrepare' => true,
     'username' => '63a9f0ea7bb98050796b649e85481845',
     'password' => 'e04ccf211208f8c97e4a36e584926e60',
     'charset' => 'utf8',
), // value by MD5 function, example only
```

Comment: If the information "how to authenticate at my sql server" resides on the server where you host your application, and it is accessible by Yii, then everyone with access can find that information. No matter whether it's a plain-text password, a hash or a private key.

Comment: You could use two way encryption, [something like this](http://www.99points.info/2010/06/php-encrypt-decrypt-functions-to-encrypt-url-data/). Make the methods static and then pass `Encryption::decode(my_encoded_username)` to `username`, `password` etc. I'm not sure if Yii loads classes in the config file, however.

Comment: @Örs: What is that going to accomplish? You need to get the encryption key from somewhere. If that somewhere is accessible along with your source, anyone with access to the source can decrypt the password. If it's not, just put the password itself there and there's no need to involve encryption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot conceal the credentials from someone who has access to your source as long as you are using [native MySql authentication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/native-authentication-plugins.html). That's because your code needs to pass the credentials as cleartext¹ to the server, so it needs to be able to "decrypt" them before connecting. Someone who has access to your source can follow the same procedure and decrypt them as well.

You could secure your system by relying on some type of [PAM authentication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pam-authentication-plugin.html) instead of user-supplied credentials, but Yii does not support such.

---

¹note: This is not actually true. The client passes a *hash* to the server, but it needs to have access to the original password in order to hash it. This means that for the purposes of this discussion it makes no difference (it would make a difference for someone who is listening on the network).

Answer (score 0):

Using Yii 1.x I did it using below method.

1. create a class, `DbConnection` inside `protected/components`  extending from `CDbConnection`

   `class DbConnection extends CDbConnection 
   {
       public function createPdoInstance()
       {
           // Decrypt the password used in config file
           // e.g.: $this->password = mydecrypt($this->password);
           return parent::createPdoInstance();
       }
   }`
2. Adjust the config file (`protected/config/main.php`)

   `'db' => array(
       'class' => 'DbConnection', // Use above classname
       'password' => 'encryptedpassword',
   ),`